# Using select to poll connections - TCP server

Tags: perl, sockets

```
use strict; use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;
my $read_select  = IO::Select->new();
my $write_select = IO::Select->new();

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
            LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
            LocalPort => '5556',
            Proto => 'tcp',
            Listen => 50,
            Reuse => 1,
 ) or die "Could not create socket: $!";

 print "Socket Created . Waiting for connection ...\n";

 ## poll to accept new connection or to receive data from a connection

 $read_select->add($socket);

 print "Added socket to read list ";
 my $reade;
 my $newconn;
 my @read;
 my @write;
 while(1) {
    @read = $read_select->can_read();

    foreach my $reade(@read) {
            if($reade == $socket) {
                    print "New conn received";
                    my $newconn = $reade->accept();
                    $write_select->add($newconn);

            }
            else {
                    print "data received";
            }
    }
 }
 @write = $write_select->can_write();

 foreach my $write(@write) {
    $write->send("got ur data");
 }
```

I am trying to poll for connections using select statement. Why is that if i use an infinite loop, no connection is accepted. It works fine without while(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are being bitten by I/O buffering here.  Perl buffers all input and output.  It generally doesn't print to the terminal until it has received an entire line.

Your code is probably working with the `while(1)`, but you can't see the output of your debug print statements because the output to the terminal is being buffered.  Once you get to the second time through the loop, `$read_select->can_read()` blocks forever, so you *never* see the output of the print statements.

You can probably fix this just by adding `\n` to the end of each print statement.  Another option is setting `$| = 1;`.  This disables buffering.  See [perlvar's discussion of `$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) for more information on buffering.